# Python3 urllib3 crawler - can't limit max connections to aa single domain

Tags: python, urllib, urllib3

I am using python3 urllib3 in order to build a crawler to download multiple urls.

On my main activity i create 20 threads of that using **the same (one) instance** of my `Downloader` class which uses one instance of `PoolManager`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.manager = PoolManager(num_pools=20)
```

I've tried submitting the same url over and over again and i see at the log that it creates a lot of connections to the same domain. I've tried to limit number of pools (`num_pools=1`) and it still creating multiple connections to the same url. On the documentation i understood that the `PoolManager` creates a new connection if the other connections to the same domain are being used.

I want to limit the number of connection to a single domain. Using up to 2 different connections is what a normal browser use so it is safe. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PoolManager(num_pools=20)` will limit the pool to 20 cached instances of ConnectionPools, each representing one domain usually. So you're effectively limiting to 20 cached domain pools, the per-domain connections are one level deeper.

We can specify the limit per ConnectionPool with `maxsize=20`. Since you're using the pool to throttle your crawler, you'll also want to use `block=True` which will prevent creating additional connections outside of the limit. With `block=False` (the default), more connections will be created as-needed, but ones beyond the maxsize will not be saved for re-use.

Altogether, you probably want:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.manager = PoolManager(maxsize=20, block=True)
```

A bit more documentation on which parameters are available:

- [PoolManager](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/index.html#module-urllib3.poolmanager) (the remainder gets passed down to the ConnectionPool)
- [ConnectionPool](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/index.html#urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool)